# if x>0 use f(x) ,if x<0 use g(x) and plot all y in one plot

Tags: r

how would I write a function which chooses between two functions depending on whether the argument is larger or smaller zero and writes the generated values into a y vector so that one can `plot(x,y)`. Can you please tell me whether this is the right ansatz or not:

```
x <- runif(20,-20,20)
y <- numeric()
f <- function(x){      
    if(x>0){y <- c(y,x^2)}
    if(x<0){y <- c(y,x^3)}
    }
for(i in x){f(x)}
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: You can do `y <- ifelse(x<0,x^3,x^2)`

Comment: Or `x ^ ifelse(x < 0, 3, 2)` for a bit cleaner calculations

Comment: golfing... `x^(2+(x<0))`

Comment: ... or `x^(2.5-0.5*sign(x))`

Comment: someone please post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, there are few problems with your code:

1. Your function `f` does not return any meaningful values. The assignment to `y`
   is not global and remains in the scope of the function.
2. Many operations in `R` are vectorized (i.e. they are performed on the whole vectors instead of individual elements), and this is an important feature of a good `R` code, but your code does not take advantage of that. To give a gist, when you do `x > 0`, and `x` is a vector, it will return a boolean vector  where condition is checked for every element of `x`. When you do `x^2`, it returns a numeric vector where every element is a square of the corresponding element in `x`. `ifelse` is also a vectorized operator, so it also checks the condition for every element in the vector. By knowing that, you can get rid of your function and loop and do `y <- ifelse(x<0,x^3,x^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the loop, and in this case it is not even necessary to define `f(x)` and to store the output in a vector `y`.

Something like

```
x <- runif(20,-20,20)
plot(x,ifelse(x<0,x^3,x^2))
```

should do. The second argument can take several versions, as discussed in the comments.

If you want to store the function and the data for later use, try

```
x <- runif(20,-20,20)
f <- function(x) ifelse (x < 0, x^3, x^2)
y <- f(x)
plot (x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option...

```
x <- runif(20,-20,20)
y <- x^2*(x>0)+x^3*(x<=0)
plot(x,y)
```

R will interpret (x > 0) as a boolean (T or F) and then automatically transform it to 1 and 0.